# Book focused on SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can you recommend a book that is the Microsoft SQL Server equivalent of [MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100896.do), I'm looking for something with a focus on Stored Procedures, Stored Functions, and Triggers.

Comment: It might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207716/what-is-the-best-sql-book-or-web-tutorial

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719300/please-recommend-the-one-sql-book-for-a-developer-without-a-lot-of-sql-experienc

Comment: or... https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+sql+books&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+sql+books&fp=98977496438a8249

Comment: I did not see any books in any of those links with a focus on procedures, functions, or triggers. Some had a chapter or two on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Guru's Guide to SQL Server Stored Procedures, XML, and HTML

[http://www.amazon.com/Gurus-Guide-Server-Stored-Procedures/dp/0201700468](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700468)

Comment: PERFECT! I did not find this book in any searches, and looks like what I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

why not this book -> [High Performance MySQL](http://www.play.com/Books/Books/4-/5113473/High-Performance-MySQL/Product.html?searchstring=MYSQL&searchsource=0&searchtype=allproducts&urlrefer=search) ??

Comment: Please read the question

Comment: I am looking for a "Microsoft SQL Server" book not a MySQL book

Comment: My bad I read past the MS part